# nodejs - writeFile creates empty file

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to write my puppeteer result to a txt, but i cant make it work. The txt is created, but empty

I'm using process.exit, but dont know if it is the correct way

I know textContent is not empty, cause i can console log its content

```
var https = require('https');
var Q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://www.99freelas.com.br/projects'
/*const idToScrape;
deverá receber qual a url e os parametros específicos dela */
async function genScraper() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    var textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const ali = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-list li'));
        return ali.map(li => li.textContent)
    });

    fs.writeFile('res.txt', textContent, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const ali = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-list li'));
        return ali.map(li => li.innerText);
    });


    process.exit();
}
//not used
function gravaArquivo(arquivo) {
    var deferido = Q.defer();
    fs.writeFileSync('resultado.txt', arquivo, function(err) {
        deferido.resolve(true);
        console.log('aqui estou')
    });
    return deferido.promise;
}

genScraper();
```

Comment: Why are you using `process.exit()`? Have you tried leaving that off to see if the file gets written? I'm not sure it would matter, but maybe?

Comment: await your fs.writeFile call (use 'fs-extra' instead of 'fs') or run these processes in async.series to ensure they all get finished before the process.exit() fires.

Comment: i only addes process.exite because a stackoverflow question for this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.writeFile()` is an async function, so `process.exit();` is executed before the `fs.writeFile` completion.

You can either user sync version of writeFile: `fs.writeFileSync()` or put `process.exit();` inside the callback:

```
fs.writeFile('res.txt', textContent, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your fs.writeFile into a little promised function of its own:

```
const writeFile = (path, data, opts = 'utf8') =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.writeFile(path, data, opts, (err) => {
            if (err) rej(err)
            else res()
        })
    });
```

Then in your main async genScraper function, you can do:

```
await writeFile('res,txt', textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return a Boolean result denoting the success of [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback):

```
const write_file = ( file, data ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
{
    fs.writeFile( file, data, 'utf8', error =>
    {
        if ( error )
        {
            console.error( error );

            reject( false );
        }

        else
        {
            resolve( true );
        }
    });
});
```

You can use this in your `genScraper()` function using the following method:

```
if ( await write_file( 'res.txt', textContent ) )
{
    // fs.writeFile was successful
}

else
{
    // fs.writeFile was not successful (check console for error)
}
```

If this doesn't work, you may have a permissions issue for the file or directory in which you are attempting to write the data.

If you are running Linux, you may need to use [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) to change the owner of the file or directory to the current user.

Alternatively, you might want to look into using [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) to change the permissions associated with the file to allow for the current user to have write permissions.